# openpyxl: How to get multiple auto-filters on a single sheet

Tags: openpyxl, autofilter

How can I get multiple filters on a single sheet?

A single filter is easy:

```
 worksheet.auto_filter.ref = "A1:D4"
```

I can't figure out how to do multiple filters.  I tried a few things like:

```
worksheet.auto_filter.ref = "A1:D4,A6:D9"
worksheet.auto_filter.ref = "A1:D4;A6:D9"
```

but noting works.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

The specification says that there may be only a single auto-filter per worksheet.

As long as you're happy with working with a development version you might want to look at the 2.4 development branch which has much improved filtering and sort support. I don't use filters much myself so it could use some testing and the feedback would be very helpful.

The API has changed a bit and the best documentation is in the tests:

```
    af = AutoFilter('A1:F1')
    af.add_filter_column(5, ["0"], blank=True)
    ws.auto_filter = af
```

Answer (score 1):

Found out I can use tables to implement the sort/filter functionality.  And you can have multiple tables in a single sheet.  Unfortunately I can't find a way to do this in openpyxl but XlsxWriter can do this very easily.

```
worksheet1.add_table('A1:C4')
worksheet1.add_table('F8:H15')
```

Comment: Assuming you mean https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_tables.html, then it's because no one has implemented the functionality yet.